# PostgreSQL:Error while calling a custom function

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

Following is a *Function* created in `PostgreSQL 9.2` ,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getRows()
RETURNS TABLE (
        "Name" character varying
       ,"Address" text
       ,"Phone" text
       ,"Email" character varying
       ,"Tin" character varying
       ,"DL.No1, DL.No2" text
       ,"Area" character varying
) AS
$func$
BEGIN
       select  acname as "Name", coalesce(nullif(concat_ws(', ', nullif(add1, ''),  
       nullif(add2, '')), ''), 'NIL') "Address", coalesce(nullif(concat_ws(', ', 
       nullif(phoneoff, ''), nullif(mobile, '')), ''), 'NIL') "Phone",case when email 
       <>'' then email else 'NIL' end as "Email",case when email <>'' then tin else 
       'NIL' end as "Tin",case when dlno1 ||', '||dlno2=', ' then 'NIL' else dlno1 ||',  
       '||dlno2 end as "DL.No1, DL.No2",areaname as "Area" from gtab12   left  join 
      gtab47 using(areaid) where acgrcode  = '204'  order by areaname,"Name";
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When `select getRows()` an *error* is occurring

```
     ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
      HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function getRows() line 4 at SQL statement
```

---

given below is actually what the *select query* inside the *function* `getRow` returns.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `SELECT` statement in a `plpgsql` function without the `INTO` clause (you must use [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) instead).

You also forget to [`RETURN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) with something.

But, if your function is that simple, you could use a plain [`sql` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) (or even a [view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

To return a set of something, you need to use RETURN NEXT (to return a row at a time) or RETURN QUERY (to return a number of rows resulting from a query).

See the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) section relating to returning values.

Your example function would need to have:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT....;
RETURN;
```

Note the need for the second RETURN - this is needed because there may be multiple RETURN QUERY statements before the function exits.